# CSS selector :nth-child(even) Vs jQuery( ":even" )

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

jQuery selects `first row` as `even` (0 based) whereas CSS selects `second row` as `even` (1 based).
Yes, jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) clearly mentions it as an extension and not part of CSS in it's Additional note -

> Because **:even is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS**
>   specification, queries using :even cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. To achieve the best performance when using :even to select
>   elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then
>   use .filter(":even").

But shouldn't they both be the same in deciding what is even and what is odd? Why the confusion?

```js
$('ul li').filter(':even').text('jQuery Even')
```

```css
li {
  color: blue;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>CSS Odd</li>
  <li>CSS Even</li>
  <li>CSS Odd</li>
  <li>CSS Even</li>
  <li>CSS Even</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You've already identified the discrepancy: zero-based and one-based counting. To make them match, just use css's `:nth-child(even)` as a jQuery selector.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for your response. You have any references giving the reasons for keeping this discrepancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even within the documentation, it is stated that the behavior `counter-intuitively, :even selects the first element, third element, and so on within the matched set.`

As I don't think there is any technical reasons (other than the indexes being even) for this behavior, it is really more of a "why" question in terms of "why was it designed this way".  Perhaps it was easier or more intuitive to whoever created it.  The `:nth-child(even)` is part of the CSS3 selectors module specification which, as of present, is a [Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/2014/Process-20140801/#RecsPR) but at the time of `jQuery 1.0` (in 2006 when `:even` was introduced) was still a Candidate Recommendation.

As to why it is still the behavior in jQuery, that is likely for reverse compatibility since modifying the behavior could break all the existing sites and code that rely on the the legacy behavior.

Comment: Not really counter-intuitive to my taste, indexes of array-like elements in computing tend to start with `0`, which is an even number.